# Recurrence relation to find time-complexity

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have the following simple C-program:

```
int factorial(int n)
{
    if(n==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return n*factorial(n-1);
}
```

Now, if I take the recurence relation as

```
    T(n) = n*T(n-1), when n>0
    T(n) = 1, when n=1
```

then, the time complexity of this algorithm becomes O(n!), i.e., O(n^n)

and now, if I take the recurrence relation as

```
    T(n) = T(n-1) + c, where 'c' is some constant
```

then, the time complexity of this algorithm becomes O(n)

Which one is correct?

I know, the time-complexity of this algorithm is O(n), but then, how can we ignore the variable 'n' which is multiplied with the function call 'factorial(n-1)'?

Comment: What is the time complexity of computing `a` multiplied by `b`? Do you consider it to be `O(1)` or `O(ab)`?

Comment: Yes, obviously it is O(1), but your argue is not logical as according to your logic if the recurrence relation is T(n) = T(n-1) + n, then the solution will be simply a constant as if we must ignore the sum and take it as O(1) instead of the final solution as O(n^2). But it's not true na...

Comment: $O(n!)$ is not the same thing as $O(n^n)$, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

The formula describing the time complexity of an algorithm is usually completely different from the formula describing the result of an algorithm. We can see this using some simple examples:

```
int id(int n)
{
     return n;
}
```

Here the time complexity is $O(1)$, even though the function returns $n$.

Again, consider

```
int one(int n)
{
     int result = 1;
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
         result = 1;
     return result;
}
```

This (silly) algorithm has $O(n)$ time complexity, but always returns $1$.

Now, in your example,

> $T(0) = 1$ and $T(n) = nT(n-1)$ for $n>0$

is a recurrence describing the *return value* of the `factorial` function, but is not a recurrence describing the *running time*. For the running time, we need to look at the time which the operations involved take place. In particular, multiplying by $n$ in an algorithm doesn't cause the running time to be multiplied by $n$. Suppose we define $S(n)$ to be the running time of `factorial(n)`. If multiplication is $O(1)$, then, to compute `n*factorial(n-1)`, this is the time to compute `factorial(n-1)`, plus a constant amount, and we arrive at your second, correct, recurrence:

> $S(n) = S(n-1) + c$